# SQL combining a left join with a where between

Tags: sql, left-join, between

I have two queries that work perfectly.

```
SELECT fy.date_stop as pend
FROM account_fiscalyear fy
WHERE <any date> BETWEEN fy.date_start AND fy.date_stop
```

This returns the last date of the fiscal year in which  can be found.

and

```
SELECT a.id as id, COALESCE(MAX(l.date),a.purchase_date) AS date
FROM account_asset_asset a
LEFT JOIN account_move_line l ON (l.asset_id = a.id)
WHERE a.id <some condition>
GROUP BY a.id, a.purchase_date
```

This returns a results similar to the following giving the asset id and purchase date or last depreciation date for the asset.

```
61  2014-09-01
96  2014-09-01
115 2015-02-25
181 2015-11-27
122 2015-04-03
87  2014-09-01
67  2014-09-01
207 2016-09-09
54  2014-09-01
159 2015-08-25
163 2015-08-19
....
```

The result I want is the asset id but this time with the last day of the financial year that the purchase date or last depreciation date can be found in. I just don't seem to be able to find a way to combine the two queries.

Solved it.

```
SELECT a.id as id, COALESCE(MAX(l.date), a.purchase_date) as date
FROM
(SELECT ass.id as id, fy.date_stop as purchase_date
FROM account_fiscalyear fy, account_asset_asset ass
WHERE ass.purchase_date BETWEEN fy.date_start AND fy.date_stop) a
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT mvl.asset_id as asset_id, fy.date_stop as date
FROM account_move_line mvl, account_period per, account_fiscalyear fy
WHERE mvl.period_id = per.id AND per.fiscalyear_id = fy.id) l
ON (l.asset_id = a.id)
GROUP BY a.id, a.purchase_date
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? Also, there are different tables shown in the two queries, but you haven't explained the relationship between them, which would be required in order to make a join.

Comment: SELECT COALESCE(MAX(l.date),a.purchase_date) AS date
FROM account_asset_asset a, account_fiscalyear fy, 
LEFT JOIN account_move_line l ON (l.asset_id = a.id)
WHERE date BETWEEN fy.date_start AND fy.date_stop/*a.id IN %s*/
GROUP BY a.id, a.purchase_date

Comment: thanks, but it would be easier to read (and better for future readers) as an edit to the question :-)